# docker ps list only Names and Status

Tags: docker

I want to get status of docker containers with only names and status. I tried below but showing only status

```
sudo docker ps --format '{{.Names}}' --format '{{.Status}}'

Up 10 days (healthy)
```

With docker command could we get only container name and status

I want output similar like below,

```
container-Name | status
memcached      | Up 10 days (healthy)
```

Comment: docker ps  --format "container-Name | status {{.Names}} | {{.Mounts}}"

Basically you have to use go template for formatting, as official documentation suggests.

Answer (score 3):

you can have it by running this:

```
docker ps --format "table {{.ID}} | {{.Status}}"
```

This is the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/) on how to format `docker ps`

Answer (score 1):

[image]
You can use like this

```
docker ps --format "{{.ID}}     {{.Status}}"


                OR
docker ps --format "{{.ID}}||{{.Status}}"
```

[image]
Thanks @Root
Reference:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/